# Bootstrap datepicker + Django + Docker not working

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, docker

I am running into a strange problem that I have tried debugging without success. I am using the django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus library to render datepickers on certain fields on my Django forms, and they appear correctly in dev (locally) however, they do not appear when I run them in a docker setup. I have include_jquery set to True in settings, and I am not loading any other jquery files. Any suggestions?

local:
[image]

docker:
[image]

Comment: Check your browser's debugger to see what resource was not loaded!

Comment: Ah so inside the docker container it is not loading the static js file for the bootstrap-datepicker-plus library, however I am running the collectstatic command when the container starts and I double-checked that the folder is created, so not suer why it is not being loaded...